# search_fields in Django behaved strangely in Django ModelAdmin

Tags: django, search, django-admin

I have a django model admin page and wanna use its search function so I defined a search_fields like this:

```
    search_fields = (
                 'name', 'email',
                 'vacancy__position__name',
                 'vacancy__location__name',
                 )
```

Problem is the 'vacancy' field is nullable, but the search can not find items with null 'vacancy', so I dig into the sql it executed and found the problem:

```
SELECT "testapp_subject"."name", "testapp_subject"."email",
  FROM "testapp_candidate"
 INNER JOIN "testapp_subject" ON ("testapp_candidate"."subject_ptr_id" = "testapp_subject"."id")
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "testapp_vacancy" ON ("testapp_candidate"."vacancy_id" = "testapp_vacancy"."id")
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "testapp_position" ON ("testapp_vacancy"."position_id" = "testapp_position"."id")
 INNER JOIN "testapp_location" ON ("testapp_vacancy"."location_id" = "testapp_location"."group_ptr_id")
 WHERE (UPPER("testapp_subject"."name"::text) LIKE UPPER(%j%)
        OR UPPER("testapp_subject"."email"::text) LIKE UPPER(%j%)
        OR UPPER("testapp_position"."name"::text) LIKE UPPER(%j%)
        OR UPPER("testapp_location"."name"::text) LIKE UPPER(%j%) )
 ORDER BY "testapp_candidate"."subject_ptr_id" DESC
```

As you can see, the last INNER JOIN should be LEFT OUTER JOIN.

I tried to dig into the sql generating part to see what's going on but the code is too complicated to read. Anyone has a clue on what's going on or is there anyone ran into the same situation?

Following is a simplified model structure for my case.

```
class Group(models.Model):
    pass

class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

class Position(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Location(Group):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    org = models.ForeignKey(Organization)

class Vacancy(models.Model):
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now())
    filled = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Subject(models.Model):
    org = models.ForeignKey(Organization, verbose_name="organization")
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 85, null=True, blank=True)

class Candidate(Subject):
    vacancy = models.ForeignKey(Vacancy, null=True, blank=True)
```